# Error: Import by filename is not supported. For Python 2.7 on MacOS

Tags: python, macos

I wrote script, and if I run it from Pycharm - everything runs ok. No problems at all.

But, if I run it from terminal I receive error:

```
Import by filename is not supported
```

I have the project that consists of four packages and in the packages the files have some imports between files.

I run it by command:

```
python -m ~/PycharmProjects/name_of_projects/package_main/main.py
```

Import:

```
from package_name_1.file_1 import *
from package_name_1.file_2 import *
```

Comment: Could you show the import statements please?

Comment: in addition, check you interpreters - does pycharm and 'python' are the same file?

Comment: Added import statesments

Comment: What does 'pycharm' and python the same file mean? Both 2.7....

Answer (score 1):

`python --help` says:

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

By this, it means that `mod` should be something that the Python interpreter can `import`, i.e., a module located on `PYTHONPATH`. It's used for running some package, like a debugger, with your script as an argument, e.g.,

```
python -m ipdb myscript.py
```

would debug `myscript.py` instead of just running it (if `ipdb` is an installed package).

Just as you cannot write

```py
import ~/PycharmProjects/name_of_projects/package_main/main.py
```

within your script, you cannot pass that argument to `-m`.

Is there a reason you're not calling

```
python ~/PycharmProjects/name_of_projects/package_main/main.py
```

without `-m`?

Comment: In this case I receive ImportError: No module named package_defs.file_name

Comment: Then it appears that `package_defs` isn't installed as you expect it to be. It's hard to help further without seeing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.